# Error: non-static reference member, can't use default assignment operator

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm adapting an existing library ("Webduino", a web server for Arduino) to work with another existing library ("WiFly", a wifi module) and running into a problem.  Each library works fine on its own.  The Webduino library expects to use an Ethernet hardware module over SPI, whereas the WiFi module uses a serial port (UART).  The error I get is:

```
WiFlyClient.h: In member function 'WiFlyClient& WiFlyClient::operator=(const WiFlyClient&)':
WiFlyClient.h:14:
error: non-static reference member 'WiFlyDevice& WiFlyClient::_WiFly', can't use default assignment operator
WiFlyWebServer.h: In member function 'void WebServer::processConnection(char*, int*)':
WiFlyWebServer.h:492: note: synthesized method 'WiFlyClient& WiFlyClient::operator=(const WiFlyClient&)' first required here
```

Here are the relevant code snippets.  Note that so far I have only been modifying WiFlyWebServer.h (Webduino):

```
// WiFlyWebServer.h (Webduino)
...
WiFlyServer m_server; // formerly EthernetServer and
WiFlyClient m_client; // EthernetClient
...
void WebServer::processConnection(char *buff, int *bufflen){
  ...
  // line 492
  m_client = m_server.available();
  ...
}



// WiFlyClient.h
class WiFlyClient : public Client {
 public:
  WiFlyClient();
  ...
private:
  WiFlyDevice& _WiFly;
  ...
}



// WiFlyClient.cpp
#include "WiFly.h"
#include "WiFlyClient.h"

WiFlyClient::WiFlyClient() :
  _WiFly (WiFly) {    // sets _wiFly to WiFly, which is an extern for WiFlyDevice (WiFly.h)
  ...
}


// WiFly.h
#include "WiFlyDevice.h"
...
extern WiFlyDevice WiFly;
...



// WiFlyDevice.h
class WiFlyDevice {
  public:
    WiFlyDevice(SpiUartDevice& theUart);
...



// WiFlyDevice.cpp
WiFlyDevice::WiFlyDevice(SpiUartDevice& theUart) : SPIuart (theUart) {
  /*

    Note: Supplied UART should/need not have been initialised first.

   */
  ...
}
```

The problem stems from `m_client = m_server.available();`, if I comment that out the problem goes away (but the whole thing relies on that line).  The actual problem seems to be that the _WiFly member can't be initialized (overwritten?) when the WiFiClient object is being assigned, but I can't understand why it doesn't work here when it does work without modification.

(Yes, I know there's implementation in the header file, I don't know why they wrote it that way, don't blame me!)

Any insights?

Comment: `_WiFly` is [reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for the implementation.

Comment: @chris, no, it is not defined in _global_ scope. To the question - why not just define your own assignment operator? Seems `_WiFly` should be just ignored there, as it initialized correctly in construction anyway

Comment: @Lol4t0, From the link: `Reserved in any scope, including for use as implementation macros:
identifiers beginning with an underscore and an uppercase letter`. The global scope one is for starting with an underscore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `WiFly` member of your `WiFlyClient` is making the class not assignable. The reason for that is that assignment cannot be used to change which object the reference is referring to. For example:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int &ar = a;
int &br = b;
ar = br; // changes a's value to 2, does not change ar to reference b
```

Since all your `WiFlyClient`s are referencing the same `WiFlyDevice` instance, you can change `WiFlyClient` as the compiler suggests to use a static member:

```
// WiFlyClient.h
class WiFlyClient : public Client {
 public:
  WiFlyClient();
  ...
private:
  static WiFlyDevice& _WiFly;
  ...
};
```

Then, you do not initialize it in the constructor, but in a source file where you define it.

```
WiFlyDevice & WiFlyClient::_WiFly = WiFly;
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I had already tried making _WiFly static, but hadn't experimented with where to properly define it.  Now my code compiles, so time will tell if it functions properly...

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the problem is that `WiFlyClient` is not assignable.  Consider containing it in a `std::unique_ptr` (in C++03, `std::auto_ptr`) so that you can at least assign items of that type.

```
std::unique_ptr<WiFlyClient> m_client;

...

m_client = m_server.available();

...

// convert m_client.<...> to m_client-><...>

// change m_server.available() to return std::unique_ptr<WiFlyClient>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `operator=`:

```
WiFlyClient& operator= (const WiFlyClient & wi)
{
  /* make a copy here */ 
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: I looked into this and tried a couple things but I couldn't figure out the right recipe for making the copy...